# Using Git in terminal vs. GUI on github

Tags: git, github

I've used Git in the terminal and by just "dragging and dropping" with the GitHub website GUI. The latter is obviously much easier for simple situations.

Can someone elaborate the use of using the terminal to commit changes, upload files, etc. vs. just using the GitHub's GUI? Will becoming familiar with terminal Git ever be useful if my project becomes more complicated?

Comment: "The website"?  What website?  (I'm guessing you mean GitHub, but that's just one of many websites that host Git repositories.)

Comment: Sorry. Yes - www.github.com

Answer (score 2):

Generally you would be using the command line to make changes to the repository on your local machine and then pushing those changes to a remote repository (on GitHub in this case).

It's not possible to manage your local repository using the GitHub website.

I would highly advocate learning to use git through the command line. It'll help you gain a better understanding of what's happening when you execute commands.